If $a_0 \ln(x) + a_1x \ln(x) + a_2x^2 \ln(x) + \ldots $ is an example as a quasi-polynomial, then what is this?
As the title says, $a_0 \ln(x) + a_1x \ln(x) + a_2x^2 \ln(x) + \ldots $ is known as an example of a quasi-polynomial. But what would this be known as:
$a_0x + a_1x \ln(x) + a_2x \ln^2(x) + \ldots $, where this time the $x$ remains as consistent throughout each term but the logarithm is increasing in power. While you could write the first equation as:
$$\ln(x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n}x^n$$ you could write the second equation as: $$x\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n} \ln^n(x)$$
Is this still a quasi-polynomial? Or would it be considered something such as a "linear quasi-logarithm"?

It might help if you stated where you are getting this notion of "quasi-polynomial" from.  It is clearly not the same as the "quasi-polynomial" referred to by imrobert.

Why not @RobertIsrael?

@imrobert Because the coefficients are not periodic.

I got it from a definition given to me by one of my university lecturers.

No.

A quasi-polynomial can be written as $()=_()^+_{−1}()^{−1}+⋯+_0(), \mathrm{where }\ _()$ is a periodic function with integral period.

